# Name space in rest service

Tags: services, 8

I'm using the [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module for rest services.

Is it possible to add my custom namespace in rest XML output.

Comment: what do you mean 'Custom namespace'? can you please elaborate? you mean node alias? or resource alias?

Comment: xmlns:ac="http://xml.domain.com/drupal" like this in xml output. In java it gives no name space error